# WinMain command line arguments

Tags: winapi

The 3rd param to WinMain provides the command line as an unprocessed string. While that may be useful for allowing you to cope with expansion of wildcards and what-not, is there any chance that lurking somewhere in the Win32 API that there's a way to get the usual C argc, argv version of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx) to convert to an argv-style array of Unicode strings.  Unfortunately, there is no ANSI-string version.  Also, beware that this does not set `argv[argc]` (i.e. the element after the last argument) to NULL.

Answer (score 12):

microsoft speciffic:

__argc and __argv

Answer (score 2):

CommandLineToArgvW()